# Freeing resources when thread exits

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Is it possible for a thread to clean up itself when it exits? I have the problem, that my thread calls some binary blob (via a function pointer) where I have no control about the resources it may allocate and I need some way to clean up everything as soon as the thread exits. Including memory, open file descriptors, created X-windows etc. Basically what `exit()` does, just that I don't want the main thread to exit.

I am currently using pthread and intercept all calls to `malloc()`, `mmap()`, `open()` and `atexit()` from inside the thread. When the thread finishes I then call the functions registered by atexit and call `free()`, `munmap()` and `close()` for the allocated resources.

This doesn't work however, because apparently there is a lot more going on. For example, naively closing FDs from a connection to X11 will crash the whole app.

I would like the OS to handle my thread exit as if it would be a normal process. Is that possible with pthread? If not, is there maybe another threading library that could do this?

Comment: I would run a separate process.

Comment: Re “I would like the OS to handle my thread exit as if it would be a normal process”: The whole reason intra-process threads exist is to share resources within one process. If two or more things are running as separate processes, the operating system retains final control over their resources. When you request to run a thread inside your process, managing their resources is your job…

Comment: … The operating system cannot know which resources “belong” to one thread or another because it is entirely legitimate for one thread to acquire some resource and hand off conceptual ownership of that resource to another thread. Designing the application and its management of resources is your job.